# Select as a method parameter

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

In C# 8 I have the following method:

```
public Result Verify(IEnumerable<Decimal> values) { 
  // Do something with values
}
```

And class:

```
public class Point {
  public Decimal Maximum { get; set; }
  public Decimal Minimum { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using it as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = getDataPoints();

Result result = Verify(points.Select(x => x.Maximum).ToList());
```

How can I create a similar `Verify` method that I could use as:

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = getDataPoints();

Result result = Verify(points => points.Maximum);
```

I would pass the points and define which property holds the values to be used inside the method Verify

Comment: The sample code you've given *doesn't* pass `points`... it only passes a lambda expression. It would be fairly easy to write something so that you could have `Verify(points, x => x.Maximum)` though.

Comment: I haven't written c# code for a long time. But, I remember when I wanted to do some magic like that you want, I used to use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection)

Comment: @JonSkeet Just corrected

Comment: Why is it named `Verify` and what is a `Result` type?

Comment: You didn't correct what I'd pointed out at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jon said, there's a little separation between the *sequence* you're operating on and the *filter* you're applying on it. Here's how your `Verify` function should look:

```
public static Result Verify<TItem, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TItem> source, Func<TItem, TValue> filter)
{
    // do whatever here to decide your result
}
```

And to use it, you'd do something like this (notice how similar this looks to regular Linq extension methods):

```
var result = points.Verify(p => p.Maximum);
```

One note here: I *strongly* recommend trying to get rid of `TValue` in the extension method and just use your final type if you can, even at the cost of writing several overloads for this. C#'s duck typing is much weaker than C++'s (or conversely, its type safety is much stronger), and you'll find yourself unable to directly cast that `TValue` to a usable number you can do arithmetic operations on.